# Factory Girl Confirmation Validation in Model Spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

I am having trouble with Factory Girl when trying to test if email confirmation is nil.

---

Here is my model spec (user_spec.rb)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it "is invalid without an email confirmation" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, email_confirmation: nil)
    expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:email)
  end

end
```

---

Here is my model (user.rb)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email,
                  :email_confirmation

  validates :email,
    :confirmation => true,
    :email => {
      :presence => true
    },
    :uniqueness => {
      :case_sensitive => false
    }

end
```

---

Here is my factory (users.rb)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
  end
end
```

---

Custom email validator (in config/initializers)

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)

    # If attribute is not required, then return if attribute is empty
    if !options[:presence] and value.blank?
      return
    end

    if value.blank?
      record.errors[attribute] << 'is required'
      return
    end

    # Determine if email address matches email address regular expression
    match = (value.match /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i)

    # If email address is not a proper email address
    if match == nil
      record.errors[attribute] << 'must be a valid email'
    # If email address is too short
    elsif value.length < 6
      record.errors[attribute] << "is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"
    # If email address is too long
    elsif value.length > 254
      record.errors[attribute] << "is too long (maximum is 254 characters)"
    end
  end

end
```

---

I expect the *is invalid without an email confirmation* spec to pass as I set the email confirmation to nil, which should cause a validation exception on the model's **email** attribute. However, for some reason there are no validation errors on the **email** attribute causing the spec to fail. I even did a *puts* of the email and email confirmation after **FactoryGirl.build(:user, email_confirmation: nil)** to verify the email confirmation is empty (which it is). I am in need of a way to validate attribute confirmations in Factory Girl and seem to be stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, go through Rails documentation on [`ActiveRecord`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#confirmation).

`:confirmation` is not validated for null. It will be validated here for same `email`, so you can set `:email_confirmation => ""` to pass the test.

To get confirmation error when `email_confirmation` is null, add a `presence` validation to `:email_confirmation`

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't think of the nil vs blank scenario. You saved my day!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. :) Had have my share of frustrations during regular RSpec testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe

```
:email => {
  :presence => true
},
```

should just be

:presence => true,

Comment: Email is a custom validator I created, I will add that code to my original post as to not confuse people.